# Concat filter drops frames

Tags: ffmpeg

This command should produce video with 30 frames, but resulting video has only 3 frames. How to fix this?

```
ffmpeg -i f1/image1.png -i f2/image2.png ... -i f30/image30.png \
-filter_complex " \
[0]drawtext=text='text1'[t0]; \
[1]drawtext=text='text2'[t1]; \
...
[29]drawtext=text='text30'[t29]; \
[t0][t1]...[t29]concat=n=30[out]" -map "[out]" result.mp4
```

Comment: Show the **complete** log.

Comment: @llogan Hello, here's the complete log: https://pastebin.com/n8PyWXHa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the timestamps with [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts):

```
ffmpeg -i f1/image1.png -i f2/image2.png ... -i f30/image30.png \
-filter_complex " \
[0]drawtext=text='text1'[t0]; \
[1]drawtext=text='text2'[t1]; \
...
[29]drawtext=text='text30'[t29]; \
[t0][t1]...[t29]concat=n=30,setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)[out]" -map "[out]" result.mp4
```

Comment: It works, thanks!